# how to place HTML text into OpenOffice document using OpenOffice API

Tags: java, html, api, openoffice.org, uno

Lets see at this example:

1. I've got `HTML` tagged text:

   ```
   <font size="100">Example text</font>
   ```
2. I have `*.odt` (OpenDocument Text) document where I want to place this HTML text with formatting depends on HTML tags (in this example `font` tag should be ommited and text `Example text` should have 100point size font in result `*.odt` file).

I prefer (but this is not strong requirement) to use OpenOffice UNO API for Java to achieve that. Is there any way to *inject* this `HTML` text into body of `*.odt` document with simple UNO API build-in HTML-odt converter or something like this (or I have to *manually* go through `HTML` tags in text and then use OO UNO API for placing text with specific formatting - e.g. font size)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this is what I've done to achieve this (using `OpenOffice UNO Api` with JAVA):

1. Load `odt` document where we want to place `HTML` text.
2. Goto place where you want to place `HTML` text.
3. Save `HTML` text in temp file in the system (maybe it is possible without saving with http URL but I wasn't testing it).
4. Insert `HTML` into odt following [this](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Inserting_Text_Files) instructions and passing URL to temp `HTML` file (remember about converting system path to `OO` path).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter/guide/supportedformats) or you can use the xslt from [xhtml2odt](http://xhtml2odt.org/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know what you mean - convert whole HTML document to ODT file, but this is not what I want to achieve - I want to convert HTML document and write it in specific place (in marked paragraph or something like this) in existing (containing other ODT text data) ODT file.

Comment: Well, you can convert the whole html into odt and combine it to a previous odt file using ODFToolkit http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/ simple API

Comment: Yes, this is some option. If I won't find any other solution, then I will consider yours. Thanks for help.